# how to get more than one cell address out of `find` method in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, find

This little macro returns the first cell address where the zip code matches.  I need all of the cells where the zip code matches. Do I loop through somehow or does the find method offer more than one answer?

```
Sub practiceFind()

    Dim wsVendor As Worksheet:                Set wsVendor = Worksheets("vendorOutput.csv")
    Dim zipColumnVendor As Integer:         zipColumnVendor = 5
    Dim vendorRows As Integer:                   vendorRows = wsVendor.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' less 1 for label row

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = Worksheets("vendorOutput.csv").Range(Cells(2, zipColumnVendor), Cells(vendorRows, zipColumnVendor))

    Dim x As Range

    Set x = searchRange.Find(what:="10514", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    MsgBox x.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`FindNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx) on `searchRange`  with `x` to get the next match.

**Example:**

```
Sub practiceFind()

    Dim wsVendor As Worksheet:                Set wsVendor = Worksheets("vendorOutput.csv")
    Dim zipColumnVendor As Integer:         zipColumnVendor = 5
    Dim vendorRows As Integer:                   vendorRows = wsVendor.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' less 1 for label row

    Dim x As Range    

    With Worksheets("vendorOutput.csv").Range(Cells(2, zipColumnVendor), Cells(vendorRows, zipColumnVendor)) 
        Set x = .Find(what:="10514", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart) 
        If Not x Is Nothing Then 
            firstAddress = x.Address
            Do 
                MsgBox x.Address
                Set x = .FindNext(x) 
            Loop While Not x Is Nothing And x.Address <> firstAddress
        End If 
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If at least one result is found, this will will cause an endless loop.  You should capture the address of the first found cell, and loop until this address is repeated.

Comment: this looks great!  what kind of variable is `firstAddress`?

Comment: It's a `String`, [Range.Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a find, you could do a filter:

```
Set searchRange = Worksheets("vendorOutput.csv").Range(Cells(1, zipColumnVendor), Cells(vendorRows, zipColumnVendor))

With searchRange
    .AutoFilter 1, 10514
    On Error Resume Next
    Set x = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    .AutoFilter
End With

If Not x is Nothing Then MsgBox x.Address
```